# Update the Speed/Duration of a Rotation in a Storyboard

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I am trying to rotate a UserControl (Image) and programmatically adjust the speed of the rotation.

So, first, I have defined a storyboard, which rotates a wheel:

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="wheelRotation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                x:Name="leftRotation"
                Storyboard.TargetName="leftWheel"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(leftWheel.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                From="360" To="0" Duration="0:0:2"
                AutoReverse="False"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Next, I am trying to update the Duration of the rotation programmatically, adjusting the "speed" every 2 seconds:

```
leftRotation.Duration = speed1;
```

At first sight, this seems to work, especially if the changes in speed are small. But if the speed increases, at every update the wheel seems to adjust its angle a little bit more, causing "hiccups".
(if the speed increases, e.g. from 2s to 4s during a 2 minute period, the wheel seems to jump ahead for 1-2 degrees at the end, if it decreases in time, the wheel rotates back a little bit at every update)

I have also tried to implement the behavior using a fixed duration and update the SpeedRatio, but that didn't help either, those adjustments still occurred.

I am rather new to Silverlight/Windows Phone, so I do not have a deeper understanding how it works internally, I would appreciate it, if someone could give me a hint how to solve it. Thanks...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? I haven't tried changing animation "in flight" so no experience with this. Can you explain what you are doing (why the animation needs to be changed like that in runtime)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is a good idea to change the properties of a `Storyboard` / DoubleAnimation when they are in running. I would remove the `RepeatBehavior="Forever"`, so that the animation fires once, instead handling the `Storyboard.Completed` event to start your animation again each time it stops. You can then adjust the duration before it re-starts.

Comment: thanks. tried it, but the rotation pauses for around half a second before it continues, even if all I do in the completed-event is just calling `wheelRotation.Begin();`